# Book about misconceptions in physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, education

Some years ago I found a book on common misconceptions that students have about physics (about energy for example) written by a german professor (but I'm not sure).

Now I can't find it anymore, I've searched on the web but nothing.
Is there anybody that knows what book I'm talking about?

Comment: Many questions on this site offer examples of common misconceptions about physics.

Comment: There are some in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=common+misconceptions+physics+students&client=ubuntu&tbm=bks).

Comment: This was almost certainly "Altlasten der Physik" (https://www.amazon.de/Altlasten-Physik-Friedrich-Herrmann/dp/3761424434). The authors come from a somewhat alternative school of thought when it comes to teaching physics, which was hotly debated in Germany around 10 years ago. I personally think it's a gem of a book (physics PhD myself, not affiliated with the authors).